# Cannot remote desktop into a non-domain joined workgroup Windows Hyper-V Server 2012R2

Tags: rdc, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Installed Hyper-V Server 2012R2 on a server. Did NOT join the server to a windows domain.

Via sconfig.cmd I configured the network adapter, enable icmp, verified I could ping other PCs on the same lan segment and they could ping me, and enable remote desktop.

When attempting to remote desktop to the server I get this error:
[image]

As others noted this issue is caused by the fact that sconfig.cmd will only enable the firewall rules for the Domain profile. Because this server is on a workgroup you have to enable it yourself with Enable-NetFirewallRule or as the poster noted an equivalent netsh command:

**netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes**

Comment: Voting to close. You should know how to configure windows to ask questions here - and this is ABSOLUTELY BASELINE. Set up network properly, configure firewall properly. Provide error message.

Comment: In addition, you need to know how to ask a question. You've stated the problem but given us no detail about what happens and what messages you get when trying to connect.

Answer (score 5):

if you haven't done so, open the Firewall for RDP, in PowerShell:

```
 Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP"
 Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-UDP"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the firewall isn't blocking RDP. Find out what firewall profile the server is using, and ensure that RDP is allowed under that profile.

Comment: Assuming he used sconfig to configure the remote desktop on the host, this should have been handled automatically.

Comment: Eh, I did it on a new build of 2012 R2 at home just this weekend. It was allowed for the domain-profile rules, but not for the others, and it wasn't a domain machine, so I had to enable the non-domain rules.